# How to loop over rows sequentially while picking a specific column in each row

Tags: r, iteration

I am a relatively novice R user and am trying to recreate a 'Dogs of the DOW' strategy with the 6 biggest Canadian banks whereby you buy the poorest performing stock/bank from the previous year in the current year. I would like to go through each row and select the column with the preceding year's worst performer. Any suggestions or tips are greatly appreciated!

I have tried writing several versions of for loops but continue to get odd outputs. In the below code I get a list where each item is the same number?

In the code, I have a data frame (BtBB) which is the annual returns of the bank stocks from 2012 through to 2018 as the rows, and the 6 banks as the columns. BtBB_min is a vector which has 6 entries denoting which column the previous year's minimum return is in (so first value points to column 4 which is year 2012's worst performer, second value is column 2 which is 2013's worst performer etc.) BtBB_ret is meant to be the output showing the returns.

```
#Entering data
BtBB <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2012-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31", "2016-12-31", "2017-12-31", "2018-12-31"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"), 
  CIBC = c(0.08375119, 0.13442541, 0.10052910, -0.08663862, 0.20144753, 0.11847390, -0.17023013),
  RBC = c(0.151981531, 0.192551770, 0.123652150, -0.075897308, 0.225488874, 0.129635743, -0.089722358),
  National = c(0.07069587, 0.14422579, 0.11880516, -0.18466828, 0.35276606, 0.15019255, -0.10634566),
  BMO = c(0.08911954, 0.16348998, 0.16057054, -0.04989048, 0.23680840, 0.04162783, -0.11333135),
  TD = c(0.097771953, 0.195319962, 0.108869357, -0.022878761, 0.220870206, 0.112201752, -0.078615071),
  BNS = c(0.130434783, 0.156108597, -0.001806413, -0.155934248, 0.335715562, 0.085072231, -0.161119329))

BtBB_min <- apply(BtBB[-1], 1, which.min) # Finding Minimums


#Adding scalar to min vector so column numbers match properly with BtBB dataframe 
BtBB_min <- BtBB_min + 1 

#Removing last entry since only minimums from prior years matter, not current years
BtBB_min <- BtBB_min[-length(BtBB_min)]

#Removing first row from data frame since we want to reference current years
BtBB <- BtBB[-1,]

#Creating output vector for for loop
BtBB_ret <- vector("double", length = length(BtBB_min))


#Nested For loop where I'm having issue generating a proper output
for (h in seq_along(BtBB_ret)) {
  for (i in nrow(BtBB)) {
    for (j in seq_along(BtBB_min)) {
      BtBB_ret[h] <- BtBB[i,BtBB_min[j]]
    }
  }
}
```

Expect to get a vector of returns as:
.1442258, .10052910, -0.155934248, 0.3527661, 0.11847390, -0.11333135

Actually get BMO's return 6 times (-0.11333135). Can't figure out why. Have worked on this problem for like a week and can't seem to crack it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing unnecessary loops and you are overwriting the BtBB_ret values over and over again. One loop should suffice:

```
#Nested For loop where I'm having issue generating a proper output
for (i in 1:nrow(BtBB)) {
  BtBB_ret[i] <- BtBB[i,BtBB_min[i]]
}
BtBB_ret
```

Comment: Hi! that doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for. I honestly have no idea what information the code is generating? It's creating a vector of: 0.134425410, -0.001806413, -0.184668280, 0.201447530, 0.041627830, and -0.170230130. The first value _is_ in CIBC's column, but the next value _is not_ in RBC's column? Thanks!

Comment: Well, err, I read again  through your question and changed your loops. Should work properly now :)

Comment: So simple! Thank you so much!